# is there any way to decrement the IDENTITY value in SQL when a row got deleted?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am doing a project for a mobile company(where 2nd use mobiles are available for sale)....

I have created a table like

```
CREATE TABLE mobileDetails  
(  
       mobileID           INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,  
       mobileModel        VARCHAR(20),  
       price              VARCHAR(20),  
)
```

If suppose a admin logged in and add any new mobile,the new added mobile's `mobileID`
will be last existing mobileID value + 1 since we have given `mobileID` as an `IDENTITY`. 
(I am very much done with that)

but if suppose the last MOBILE's `mobileID` is 4 and i am deleting it from database....

After that if suppose I add a new mobile,then the database should give the new added mobile's ID as 4, instead its giving me 5.....

Any idea to overcome this?

Really sorry for my immature english and thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: that's the way identities work. There are ways to get around this, but I would not recommend it. I would create a separate column if you want a true incremental order.

Comment: SQL Server **does not** "recycle" or "reuse" `IDENTITY` values - and neither should you! Just use those values as is - what's the big problem with a gap (like not having a value of 4 in your table)?!?!?

Comment: Really Thanks for your help friends...actually this is a demo project for my future work in that company.....just to go ahead with mobile ID's in an order(eventhough any deletion occurs),i thought of do like that...anyways i will keep the value's as it is.....really hearty thanks for your help friends :)

Answer (score 1):

TO check current seed information on the table  use:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table_name', NORESEED)
```

For example if you delete the last record, the seed will not keep consistence:

```
Checking identity information: current identity value '8', current column value '7'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

Then you can use following query to reseed it then if insert new record it will start the seed from the deleted record:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table_name', RESEED, new_reseed_value)
```

For your case, I have created the same table like you and insert some records:

```
mobileID    mobileModel price
1   aaa 1111
2   bbbb    2222
4   aaa 1111
5   bbbb    2222
6   aaa 1111
7   bbbb    2222
8         cccc      3333
```

Then delete the last record :

```
mobileID    mobileModel price
1   aaa 1111
2   bbbb    2222
4   aaa 1111
5   bbbb    2222
6   aaa 1111
7   bbbb    2222
```

To make next record remains start from 8, I can run :

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('mobileDetails', RESEED,7)
```

Then insert 3 new records:

```
mobileID    mobileModel price
1   aaa 1111
2   bbbb    2222
4   aaa 1111
5   bbbb    2222
6   aaa 1111
7   bbbb    2222
8   aaa 1111
9   bbbb    2222
10  cccc    33333
```

Comment: I am not aware of this :) anyways i will try and let me know u :) really thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("mobileDetails", RESEED, select max(mobibleID) from mobileDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really, really sure the deleted row was the last row created in `mobileDetails` do this:

```sql
DECLARE @NewSeed AS INT;

SET @NewSeed = IDENT_CURRENT('mobileDetails') - 1;

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('mobileDetails', RESEED, @NewSeed);
```

Here is more info on `IDENT_CURRENT`: [SQL Server 2008 version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms175098(v=sql.100)) and [Current version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql)

Here is more info on `DBCC CHECKIDENT`: [SQL Server 2008 version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms176057(v=sql.100)) and [Current version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql)